# Can't setImageURI(). Why?

Tags: android, mobile, mobile-development

I want to add images to the ViewHolder. I do everything in method onBIndViewHolder(). I get String variable path from db, try to parse it by Uri and setImageUri, but it doesn't work. For debuggind I log path to the console.

```
String imgPath = images.get(position);
Log.d("imgTag", imgPath);
Uri imageURI = Uri.parse(imgPath);
//holder.image.setImageURI(imageURI);
```

Path of the image from log:

```
/document/image:46277
```

If I set image by setImageResource() it works fine, but I need from URI.

Comment: That is no valid file system path.

Comment: Its a part of a content scheme. Use the whole content scheme. Use the whole original uri.